# formatting table after saving as pdf in jspdf

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I'm trying to save google chart's table as pdf. I'm using following code.

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#customers')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    },
    margins);
 pdf.save('Test.pdf');
}
```

It is working fine and saving the table as pdf. My question is how to get it tabular format. table data in the pdf is coming line by line as text.
I'm using the following link's code :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/1/
```

I'm getting data in pdf as below:

```
Country
Population
Date
Age
Chinna
1,363,480,000
March 24, 2014
19.1
India
1,241,900,000
March 24, 2014
17.4
United States
317,746,000
March 24, 2014
4.44
Indonesia
249,866,000
July 1, 2013
3.49
Brazil
201,032,714
July 1, 2013
2.81
```

I need it in a tabular format.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in firefox, what are you trying it in?

Comment: It is working but i'm nt able to get tabular format. I have added pdf result,

Comment: Which browser? It works in firefox, the pdf displays as it should

Comment: Hmm.. I tried in chrome and firefox.

Comment: I was using wrong js file. I used jspdf.debug.js and the format issue is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included all the following script files

```
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js">   </script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/plugin/jsPdf/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```